# Where for list property Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

I have two entities 
`GasStationSummary` which contains a list of `FuelSummary`

```
public class GasStationSummary
{ ...

    public virtual List<FuelSummary> FuelSummary { get; set; } = new List<FuelSummary>();
}
 public class FuelSummary
{
    public int GsSummaryId { get; set; }

    public int FuelId { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

I get gas stations:

```
this.repository.ListAsync().Include(x => x.FuelSummary)
```

I want to get gas stations with a list of fuelTypes where FuelId is equeal to `1`

Is there a way to do so using Entity Framework?

Comment: `Where(x => x.FuelId == 1)`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere No, x doesn't have property FuelId - x.FuelSummary[i] has it

Comment: FYI, it's pretty confusing to have a list property whose name is the same as the type that it contains. Since it's a collection type, you might consider making it plural: `GasStationSummary.FuelSummaries`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a projection

```
   this.repository.ListAsync().Where(u => u.FuelSummary.Any(e => e.FuelId == 1)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x,
                Fuels = x.FuelSummary.Where(e => e.FuelId == 1)
            });
```

OR a library [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/) with `IncludeFilter`